# Easiest way to add immediate task to a `CFRunLoop`?

Tags: c++, c, cocoa, cfrunloop

What is the easiest way to add an immediate one-time task to a `CFRunLoop` from a C/C++ program, that is, a callback which must be invoked by the run-loop before it blocks again.

According to the documentation, we have `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()`, but the problem with it, is that it uses the block-notation which requires Objective-C compilation mode.

Is there something similar to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()` which is available to a C/C++ program, or am I forced to use a zero-delay timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block language feature does not require the use of Objective-C. It's also supported in C and C++ by Clang. So, you can go ahead and use `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()`.

If you're still looking for alternatives and you wish to target the main thread's run loop (i.e. the main run loop), you can use `dispatch_async_f()`. Although it's most common to use the block-based functions when using GCD, the functions with the `_f` suffix take function pointers.

```
static void my_task_function(void *context)
{
    // ...
}

...

dispatch_async_f(dispatch_get_main_queue(), any_pointer_you_like, my_task_function);
```

Comment: Cool, I just discovered the same thing, namely that blocks are available in C too: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html.